# Independence of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Suppose we have a family $(Y_i, i\in\mathbb{I})$ of independent random variables. Then if we have measurable functions of those random variables, they are also independent. However, my question is: If for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $(Y_1,\ldots ,Y_{n+1})$ is a finite collection of independent random variables, does that imply that $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y_{1} +\cdots+Y_{n+1}$. And if so, how does one prove this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's true that measurable functions of those random variables are also necessarily independent.  Or do you mean functions each of one variable, applied only to one value of $i$?

Comment: Did you mean to write "$Y_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$"?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the easy answer is: no. As a counterexample, consider $Y_1,Y_2\sim U\left([0,1]\right)$ and let $X=Y_1+Y_2$. Your question is then: are $Y_2$ and $X$ independent? However, easy implications such as
$$X\leq\frac{1}{2}\ \implies\ Y_2\leq\frac{1}{2}$$
$$Y_2\geq\frac{1}{2}\ \implies\ X\geq\frac{1}{2}$$
show that $Y_2$ and $X$ are not independent.

---

**Edit:**
Judging from the comments, the question is not: *Show that $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y_1+\ldots+Y_{n+1}$*, but *Show that $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y_1+\ldots+Y_{n}$*

1. $Y_{n+1}$ and $Y_1$ are independent, such that
   $$P(Y_{n+1}|Y_1)=P(Y_{n+1})$$
2. $Y_{n+1}$ and $Y_2$ are independent, such that
   $$P(Y_{n+1}|Y_2)=P(Y_{n+1})$$
3. Combining this shows
   $$P(Y_{n+1}|Y_1,Y_2)=P(Y_{n+1})$$
4. Generalizing this shows
   $$P(Y_{n+1}|Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n)=P(Y_{n+1})$$

Thus $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$. Thus $Y_{n+1}$ is also independent of $Y_1+Y_2+\ldots+Y_n$.

Comment: btw, if you meant to ask: _does that imply that_ $Y_{n+1}$ _is independent of_ $Y_1+\ldots+Y_n$, that is correct.

Comment: Exactly, but how do you proove it?

Comment: I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Thus Yn+1Yn+1 is independent of Y1,Y2,…,YnY1,Y2,…,Yn. Thus Yn+1Yn+1 is also independent of Y1+Y2+…+YnY1+Y2+…+Yn. But why does that hold is my question

Comment: Please use MathJax, I find it difficult to understand what it is you ask.

Comment: Why is Y(n+1) independent of the sum Y1 +... +Yn is my question

Comment: I've added that to my answer. Which step don't you understand?

Comment: The last one, you've just made a statement that you haven't proved

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_2$ have some distribution with expectation $E_2$.

Then $E(Y_2+Y_1|Y_1=a)=E_2+a$, while $E(Y_2+Y_1|Y_1=b)=E_2+b$. This is enough to say that the two conditional distributions differ.